# How to hide alert message when a process is killed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am developing one app in that there is a one scenario in which i'm trying to block running app by killing the process id (PID of running app) through terminal using the following code. To the following method i'm passing the name of running app.

**Code Snippet:**

```
-(void)lock:(NSString *)name
{
    NSString *kil = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"killall -6 %@",name];
    system([kil UTF8String]);
}
```

That time i am getting one alert message given below

> **"Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple"**

I want to hide that alert message to the user. So please suggest me if there is any way out.

Comment: please leave a comment along with the down vote.

Comment: If you want to kill it without getting the message you should use signal `9`, not signal `6`

Comment: That worked.Can you write this on answer so that I can accept it or I should delete the question?

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons for the 'quit unexpectedly' message. The termination of the process as a result of certain signals (`SIGABRT`, `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS`) are the most common reasons. The full list of signals are, by default:

```
 3     SIGQUIT      quit program
 4     SIGILL       illegal instruction
 5     SIGTRAP      trace trap
 6     SIGABRT      abort program (formerly SIGIOT)
 7     SIGEMT       emulate instruction executed
 8     SIGFPE       floating-point exception
 10    SIGBUS       bus error
 11    SIGSEGV      segmentation violation
 12    SIGSYS       non-existent system call invoked
```

As a developer, you can intercept these signals and cause different behaviour, but if the signal handlers are left to their defaults, then any of these signals will trigger the behaviour.

When you send a `-6` signal you're sending a `SIGABORT` signal, which triggers the message.

If you kill it with either `TERM` (`-15`, the default for kill), or with `KILL` (`-9` aka kill with extreme force) then it doesn't report the application as having terminated because these are what are considered 'intent' signals - i.e. you intentionally are trying to kill the process and as such should not be receiving a message in this case.